# Нет авторизации с новыми юзерами spring security

Tags: sql, spring, безопасность, boot

не происходит авторизация юзера кидает в браузере 302 ошибку, но входят те пользователи которые находятся до 69 места.

[image: Таблица для юзеров]

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
@Autowired
private DataSource dataSource;

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.httpBasic().and()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/css/**", "/js/**", 
     "/images/**","/","/index","/second_page",
    "/registration","/androidreg","/json123 
    ","/json","/json222").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
            .and()
                .logout()
                .permitAll().and();
}

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource)
            .usersByUsernameQuery("select username,password,active from usr 
             where username =?")
            .authoritiesByUsernameQuery("select u.username, ur.roles from 
             usr u inner join user_role  ur on u.id = ur.user_id where 
             u.username=? ");
  // auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("table").password("1234").roles("ADMIN");
}
@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}
}
```

Comment: 1) В каком виде запросы приходят на сервер? как для тех, кто авторизуется, так и для тех, кто пролетает. 2) Зачем нужен в тексте вопроса этот скриншот? Мы и так поверим, что есть "юзеры после 69 места".

Comment: отправляются post запросы